# image texture node - Image sequence control by slider

Tags: texturing, node-editor, image

Is there a way, how to change images from image sequence by slider or driver?

Answer (score 2):

I founded the solution, its alittle bit tricky and not fully suported at this time, but.

A) Set a driver to offset in Image texture node set to image sequence:

[image]

B) Create an object or custom property, but object responce was better for me, and write #frame to any slider (Z scale in my situation) and tap enter > it create a driver.

[image]

C) In offset driver find the scale value from object you set in and the value where is set your image number it must be integer so I rounded it. And voila.

**Pros:** It can be done.

**Cons:** In viewport - refresh image is not fully working after change the slider - you can see right result only in render view.
In blender 2.80 it is not working at all. But I hope it will be. I am looking forward to make sume flat puppets and re-drawing the phases of hands and faces trough grease pencil it will be awesome.

Comment: Why do you just not put `-frame` in Expression?

Comment: when I tried the solution -frame was somekind bugged in expression